# Why and when use append() instead of concat() in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have read all topics on `append` vs `concat` here, but still:
Why should I use `append` if `concat` has the same options and funcionallity?

Please correct me if I am mistaken.

- `append()` : can append two data frames at once; it's the same as concat in `axis=0`
- `concat()` : can concatenate multiple DFs

To concatenate multiple DFs, should I use `append()` with a for-loop? Is it faster?

Let's assume that I am opening DFs from different files like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in file_folder:
    df = df.append(pd.read_csv(file))

OR 

df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in file_folder:
   df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_csv(file)])
```

The output is the same. So why?

**EDIT:** to speed it up should I do:

```
df_list = []
for file in file_folder:

    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file))

#and then use concat

df_all = pd.concat(df_list)`
```

right?

Comment: From source: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.5/pandas/core/frame.py#L7614-L7752, a call to `append` essentially calls `concat`.

Comment: `df_list` is already a list, you can just pass it to `concat` directly.

Comment: The whole point of `concat` is to take a *list* of frames to concatenate, not just 2-item lists that wouldn't provide any benefit over something like `df.append(*list_of_two_dfs)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`append` is a convenience method which calls `concat` under the hood. If you look at the [implementation](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.5/pandas/core/frame.py#L7614-L7752) of the `append` method, you will see that.

```
def append(...
    ...
    if isinstance(other, (list, tuple)):
        to_concat = [self, *other]
    else:
        to_concat = [self, other]
    return concat(
        to_concat,
        ignore_index=ignore_index,
        verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
        sort=sort,
    )
```

As for the performance. Both of these called over and over in a loop can be computationally expensive. You should just create a list and do one concatenation after you are done looping.

From [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

> iteratively appending rows to a DataFrame can be more computationally
> intensive than a single concatenate. A better solution is to append
> those rows to a list and then concatenate the list with the original
> DataFrame all at once.

Comment: thanks, so my code for concat is okay, but for speed it up i can do as i did in edits?

Comment: Almost. You need to populate the list with dataframes, not just strings. The rest is ok.

Comment: ok i think i know what you mean, see my edits now

Answer (score 5):

Since other answers are old, I would like to add that `pd.append` is now deprecated in favour of `pd.concat` with pandas 1.4. Thus, what follows are useful information for people running into this issue today.

To concatenate multiple data frames, you should not use `append()` with a for-loop, because it can be computationally expensive and slow. You should create a list of data frames and then use `concat()` once on the list. For example:

```py
# Create an empty list of data frames
df_list = []

# Loop over the files and append each data frame to the list
for file in file_folder:
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file))

# Concatenate the list of data frames into one data frame
df_all = pd.concat(df_list)
```

This way, you avoid creating intermediate copies of the data frames and reduce the memory usage and execution time.

| Example | Using concat() | Using append() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Append two data frames row-wise | df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0) | df = df1.append(df2) |
| Append two data frames column-wise | df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1) | df = df1.join(df2) |
| Concatenate multiple data frames row-wise with different columns | df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0, join='outer') | df = pd.DataFrame() for df_i in [df1, df2, df3]: df = df.append(df_i) |
| Concatenate multiple data frames row-wise with common columns | df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0, join='inner') | df = pd.DataFrame() for df_i in [df1, df2, df3]: df = df.append(df_i, join='inner') |
| Concatenate multiple data frames with a hierarchical index | df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0, keys=['one', 'two', 'three']) | df_dict = {} for key, df_i in zip(['one', 'two', 'three'], [df1, df2, df3]): df_dict[key] = df_i df = pd.concat(df_dict.values(), axis=0, keys=df_dict.keys()) |

As it is clear, `concat()` uses more concise syntax and is faster. Thus, no reason to use `append()`.

---

Even if you like the deprecated `pd.append`, remember that the `pd.concat` function is more efficient and faster than the `pd.append` function and has the same options and functionality. Like Matus Dubrava mentioned, `append` calls `concat` under the hood anyway.

Answer (score -1):

1. **It is an arbitrary choice to either use `.append()` or `.concat()`** 

   For example if you have to merge two dataframes on `axis=1` then go with `concat` and on the other hand if you have to merge two dataframes on `axis=0` go with whatever choice you prefer to use or works best for you!
2. **Personally I would reccomend you to go with the pandas default DF merger(concat) to avoid any delays, latencies and most importantly bugs in you code.**

Hope so that you find this information useful and answers you question!
Happy Coding!